# segmentation fault (core dumped) - Pyodbc & mdbtool

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8, pydoc, mdbtools

I have to connect the mdb file by using pyodbc , the connection should be established, When i fetch data from the cursor by using cusor.fetchall(),i get error for **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

```
    con = pyodbc.connect('DSN=CHN')
    csr = con.cursor()
    csr.execute("SELECT * FROM DeviceLogs")
    att_records = csr.fetchall()
```

1. Python-2.7.12
2. pyodbc=3.1.1 or pyodbc=4.0.10
3. mdbtool

Pls help me...